# Need Help Installing Ubuntu. Mouse and Keyboard Not Working During Installation, but IOMMU Breaks my Installation

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, mouse

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my computer, but I have an issue. My keyboard and mouse don't respond when I am at the first stage of installation (Language selection). I tried enabling IOMMU, but when I do so, I get an error like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqdYG.jpg)

I'm not sure whats wrong and I would really like to get this fixed ASAP. any suggestions?

Also, when IOMMU is disabled, it just says the stuff about the PCC probe, then it starts up, but once again, my mouse and keyboard don't work so I can't continue., and when IOMMU is enabled, it gives all the spam on the screen.

Thanks for the help

Comment: USB-keyboard and mouse? If yes: make sure to connect them to motherboard USB-connectors. if that doesn't work: try to find an old PS/2 -style keyboard/mouse to attach if possible.

Comment: I was able to fix that issue. Thanks a bunch! Now, I have another issue, however and I was hoping you might know what to do. After installing Ubuntu and getting it running, I can't connect to the internet on either Ethernet or wifi. My Ethernet connection detects the network and starts connecting, but then it fails, only to try again, and fail again. any ideas?

Comment: Please mark the answer below as accepted if it helped you. Also add comments to tell what you did so that can help others with the same problem, the answer may also get updated with your info. Please open a new question for a new subject, but first try to look up relevant answers. Remember to include as much detail as possible in your question, if it ends up there.

Comment: If I turn off IOMMU then my internet works but my mouse USB Optical mouse doesn't. If I turn on IOMMU then my internet works but not my USB Optical mouse. Try that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue with newer motherboards I assume. Even changing the option in BIOS for USB legacy doesn't seem to work. What did work for me was the [OPs comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668681/need-help-installing-ubuntu-mouse-and-keyboard-not-working-during-installation/849073#comment966585_668891)

> I plugged the mouse and keyboard into the USB 3.0 motherboard ports
>   rather than the USB 2.0 ports they were already connected to.

I had been struggling with this for quite sometime. Would always try multiple USB ports, but always the 2.0 ports. Assumed 3.0 ports were newer so wouldn't work.

If you have USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports on your motherboard, connecting to the USB 3.0 port does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using an USB-keyboard and mouse:
   make sure to connect them to motherboard USB-connectors.
2. If the above doesn't work:
   try to find an old PS/2 -style keyboard/mouse to attach if possible.

---

Why:
1 - there might be trouble recognizing devices attached via complicated nesting through hubs and other devices.
2 - the safe old hardware that still often works, better than USB at times.

Comment: I plugged the mouse and keyboard into the USB 3.0 motherboard ports rather than the USB 2.0 ports they were already connected to. Now everything is in working order as far as that goes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

tried everything on a asus mobo. Old but had usb 3, sata 3 and i5 intel possibility.  Nothing worked.  Finally an old windows usb startup disk..  installing windows 10... without internet connected...  After i inserted ubuntu 22.4 live, and after the second boot and bios changes , finally ubuntu was booting and installing.  trick seems to be, to have a windows install running and using the drivers or whatever...   but sometimes the iso is available but the live disk tool works only in a linux distro, but a windows version of that bootable distro is available... ??? anyways... keep a windows usb install version in the drawer... you never know when it comes in handy ;-0)   Struggled for more than a week, but now linux is running on that brick..  ;-*